# WiFi connecting, but no Internet access

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

Since a few days, my pc running 16.04 cannot access the Internet anymore. I have tried disabling Ipv6, swapping the USB network adapter and changing the power management behavior, but none worked. 
All other devices connected to the WiFi have Internet access, even the Windows 10 installation on the same pc.

Some info: 
USB network adapter: tl-wn725n v2
WiFi Router: tl-wdr3600

`ifconfig` output:

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:cb:8a:ed:03:8f  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:585 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:585 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:40003 (40.0 KB)  TX bytes:40003 (40.0 KB)

wlxc46e1f271df7 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:6e:1f:27:1d:f7  
      inet addr:192.168.0.104  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::c66e:1fff:fe27:1df7/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:381 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:92 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:6599 (6.5 KB)  TX bytes:25095 (25.0 KB)
```

`route -n` output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

Pinging the router worked, pinging 8.8.8.8 resulted in 100% package loss.

`sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1 dev wlxc46e1f271df7` and `sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1 dev wlxc46e1f271df7` (tried both because I wasn't sure which one) both resulted in error message: `SIOCADDRT: No such device`

(PS: I'm a beginner, so please tell me what further info is needed to help me)

(PPS: I cannot connect my pc using Ethernet because it is too far away from the WiFi router)

Comment: First of all check if your interface has IP address -> `ifconfig`. Then check if you can reach your router -> `ping router_ip_address`. Then check if you can reach internet without DNS -> `ping 8.8.8.8`. Depending on what of this steps work or not, it's possible to better identify the failure.

Comment: There are other devices in your network which are able to navigate correctly? Please, add the output of `route -n`.

Comment: You are connected to the router. The problem is in the router or behind it.

Comment: @Pilot6 I do not think so, because all other devices connected to the network have access to the internet.

Comment: if your post is correct, you don't have a routing table. Try this command and tell us what happens. `sudo route add default gw 'router_ip_address' dev wlxc46e1f271df7` (weird wifi iface name :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You have to replace 'router_ip_address' with the IP address of your router.

Comment: @migrc Oops... could've guessed that myself. But which one again is my router's IP?

Comment: You said before that pinging the router worked, so... Anyway it should be 192.168.0.1

Comment: This could help you regarding adding routes in your routing table http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/siocaddrt-file-exists-ubuntu-linux-error-solution/

Comment: Without having done anything else, when starting my pc to try @Ejaz 's suggestion, it now somehow works like a charm. I have no idea why.

Comment: May be a restart was required after you made all those network configuration changes?

Comment: @Ejaz I don't think so. When you look at the dates of the suggestions, that was a few days ago. I tried restarting after trying those things a few times.

Answer (score 0):

As the other suggestions, you need to fix your route first. If not sure which one is the IP of your router you can check that on your windows checking the networking details.
Try sudo to make sure you are running the ifconfig command with permissions.